# How can I draw polylines with constant width when in .satelliteFlyover mode?

Tags: swift, width, mapkit

I have polylines drawn with mapView.mapType set to .satelliteFlyover. Using a generic MKOverlayRenderer method the lines are not a constant width.

[image]

ChatGPT came up with some code that actually works.. to a point. I had to modify a few lines but it does what I want it to do. It subclasses MKPolylineRenderer:

```
class CustomPolylineRenderer: MKPolylineRenderer {
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        super.draw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, in: context)
        let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: self.path)
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 170
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        context.strokePath()
    }
}
```

After creating the polyline it's call with the mapView delegate:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline

            return CustomPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline!)
}
```

[image]

This works great but the issue is that I can't figure out how to change the width or color of the line within the CustomPolylineRenderer class. So really my quesiton is how do you create a polyline that doesn't change width when uing .satelliteFlyover?

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to change the width or color of the line within the CustomPolylineRenderer class"* - are you asking how to change these two lines: `context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)` and `let lineWidth: CGFloat = 170` ?

Comment: Well, yes, that will work for one definition of the class. I have 8 different colors and line widths I need to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKPolylineRenderer` already has `fillColor` and `lineWidth` properties (via `MKOverlayPathRenderer`) so you can make use of those:

```
class CustomPolylineRenderer: MKPolylineRenderer {
    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        super.draw(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, in: context)

        let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: self.path)
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context.setStrokeColor((fillColor ?? .green).cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        context.strokePath()
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let polyline = overlay as? MKPolyline

    let renderer = CustomPolylineRenderer(overlay: polyline!)
    renderer.fillColor = .blue
    renderer.lineWidth = 110
    return renderer
}
```